# Gradle pattern match dependency version to ignore classifier

Tags: gradle

My understanding is that Gradle used to use Ivy to resolve dependencies but now has its own approach. I would like to be able to say "get me version 1.2.+ but don't include anything with a classifier". So, it would resolve version 1.2.33 but not 1.2.34-MyClassifier. Can Gradle be configured in this way? The Ivy documentation indicates how we could do the job in Ivy...

(from the Ivy docs)

**Version Pattern Matcher**

The version pattern matcher allows for more flexibility in pattern matching at the cost of adding a matcher declaration in Ivy settings. A simple example is given below.

Settings.xml

```
<pattern-vm>
  <match revision="foo" pattern="${major}\.${minor}\.\d+" args="major, minor" matcher="regexp" />
</pattern-vm>
```

Ivy.xml

```
<dependency org="acme" name="tool" rev="foo(1, 3)" />
```

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.4.0/settings/version-matchers.html

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution to this problem?